# CYGWIN SSHD service not starting

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, cygwin, sshd

To setup Hadoop I am installing CYGWIN on my 32 bit Windows 7 machine. It has installed successfully without any error.

```
CYGWIN Setup version : 2.774
$ uname -r : 1.7.17(0.262/5/3)
```

SSHD installed successfully, When I try to start `CYGWINSSHD` from `services.msc` either it doesn't start OR it starts and stops instantaneously. 
when I start it using cygwin termical it says..

```
$ net start sshd
The CYGWIN sshd service is starting.
The CYGWIN sshd service could not be started.
The service did not report an error.
More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3534.
```

I have googled a lot tried a lot.. but didnt succeeded.

**P.S.**

- Also tried with disabled firewall and anti virus.
- Installed CYGWIN and always start terminal as Administrator.

How can I resolve this and make `sshd` start, running smoothly when ever I start it?

Any help would be great to me. Thanks!

Comment: What does `/var/log/sshd.log` say?

Comment: What does `NET HELPMSG 3534` say?

Comment: have you run `ssh-host-config` and `ssh-user-config`?

Comment: @devnull it says `"Privilege separation user sshd does not exist"`

@dawud yes run `ssh-host-config` but not `ssh-user-config`.

Comment: Okay, Thanks @devnull because of your guidance I found a link and that solved my problem : http://codept.blogspot.in/2007/11/privilege-separation-user-sshd-does-not.html

But now when I run `ssh localhost` it says `Connection closed by ::1`. What to do now?

Comment: Does `ssh -v localhost` give any further clue?  Check `sshd_config`: is password authentication enabled?

Comment: Here is the output..

$ ssh -v localhost
..........
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/manu/.ssh/id_rsa
Connection closed by ::1

Comment: Here is what in found in `C:\cygwin\etc` 
`"# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes"`

Comment: Did you use the default privileged account while executing `ssh-host-config`?  If so, try `ssh -v cyg_server@localhost`.

Comment: yes you are right.. can you please tell me what is the default password for `ssh -v cyg_server@localhost` ?

Comment: You'll need to uncomment `#PasswordAuthentication yes` in `sshd_config`, i.e. the line should read `PasswordAuthentication yes`.

Comment: The password would be what you supplied while executing `ssh-host-config`!

Comment: ohh, Sorry. How do I change or bypass the authentication process then?

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by @devNull I read `/var/log/sshd.log` and file said `Privilege separation user sshd does not exist`. When googled the issue found a [BlogPost](http://codept.blogspot.in/2007/11/privilege-separation-user-sshd-does-not.html) that solved my problem smoothly and that instructed to

Add this line into `/etc/passwd` file,

```
sshd:x:74:74:Privilege-separated SSH:/var/empty/sshd:/sbin/nologin
```

and this line into `/etc/group` file,

```
/etc/group:sshd:*:27:
```

**P.S. :** *The purpose of this answer is just to maintain a log/StickyNote to the problem and its solution for self and others.*

Answer (score 0):

I had deleted the `sshd` user on my machine. Simply creating a standard user with name `sshd` resolved this problem for me.